# C Length of Array (filled)

Tags: c, arrays

i want to check the size of a array (the filled size).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char name[10];
    puts("Write your name");
    scanf("%2s", name); //test

    size_t n = sizeof name / sizeof *name;
    printf("size: %d",n); //result 10

}
```

I want to get the result 4 (for test)

Comment: because name is test => scanf("%2s", name); //type in "test"

Comment: i guess it would be nice to check OP's reputation points before downvoting.according to OP,he does not have an answer and has tried and had been probing with wrong keywords in his search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strlen function from string.h should do your work.

Answer (score 6):

The size of the array will not change. It will always show the number of bytes allocated for the array. What you need is the length of the string and you can get it using the function `strlen`.

Comment: More accurately, for an array with a statically declared size like this, it will return the number of elements in the array. (This happens to be equal to the number of bytes for an array of type `char` but it's worth being clear on what the operator does.)

Comment: Not true for an it array it will return for times the number of elements

Answer (score 0):

Some basics :

To OP : Why did you put the %2s format specifier in scanf ?

------> It allows you to take only the first two characters of the string as output.
        Use simple scanf %s .

Now the answer :

Filling of a character array with a string :

In the memory array ( a continguous memory block ) looks like this

```
       ---------------------------------------------------------
      | 't' | 'e' | 's' | 't' | '\0' |  Rest all are also '\0'  |                
       ---------------------------------------------------------
        0      1     2     4     5      6      7     8      9
```

And sizeof(array) will give you the size of array i.e. 10 here since char has size =1.

sizeof(char *array) gives you the size of first element of the array i.e. a char (size =1).

So, you get the result 10. Dividing array size by size of its element will give you the size of the entire block.

To get the size of filled array :

Search for the first null char in the array.

```
   int i=0;

   for(i=0;i<10;i++)

       { if(name[i]==NULL) break; }

   printf("Size is %d\n",i);
```

OR Use the strlen function included in string.h library which does it for you.

```
  #include <string.h>   {......... printf("Size is %d\n",strlen(name));......}
```